# after or before pseudoelements doesn't work on input elements

Tags: css

Hello I'm trying to use `::after` to put some text after a submit button, 
I tried to use this on a `<p>` element and it works fine, but on form elements of `input` it doesn't work.

here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
input[type='submit']::after {
content: 'some text';
}


</style>
</head>
<body> 

<form>
  
  <input type='submit'> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `pseudo-elements` won't apply to void elements like `input` and `img`

Comment: see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Comment: In a nutshell: `pseudo-elements` only apply to "container" elements, or elements which can contain other elements, and not "self-closing" elements which cannot contain other elements.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to apply pseudoclass for  `<img>` , `<input>`.

**Explanation**

In  HTML there having some empty elements listed below,

```
<area>
<base>
<br>
<col>
<embed>
<hr>
<img>
<input>
<keygen>(HTML 5.2 Draft removed)
<link>
<meta>
<param>
<source>
<track>
<wbr>
```

My understanding is that you can’t use pseudo elements for empty elements, which doesn't have any closing tag.

Comment: Try explaining why so that the OP understands...

Comment: I have updated the explanation, thanks :)